How to restrict the table row height effectively
I'm trying to set the height of a row without the inner content of a cell affecting this row height (i.e. if the content of that cell or the element(s) within, that should affect the row height).
I received some great advice to use height: inherit on the <td>, but that doesn't seem to be taking into account the border width. It seems as if that's added on top of the row height (the row height is 21px when inspected in Chrome/Safari dev utils).
How can I make the table cells/rows to stick to the 20px without explicitly setting their height individually? Note, I'm not after an explanation about the border box model as partially answered in this SO question. My intuition about the cause of the height's too high value is solely based on experimentations (i.e. increasing the border's width and observing half of it being added to the overall height). I don't know for a fact that this is the reason, and I'm genuinely looking for a solution for this specific problem of how to restrict the row height irrespective of the content's height.
I also experimented with height: 100% on the inner div (child of <td>), but that didn't restrict the height of the div and allowed it to show the entire 30px text.


td {
  height: inherit;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
<table style='box-sizing: border-box; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;'>
  <tr style='height: 20px'>
    <td>
      <div style='height: inherit;'>
        <div style='font-size: 30px; background-color: green'>Foobar</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test2</td>
  </tr>
    <tr style='height: 20px'>
    <td>
      <div style='height: inherit'>
        <div style='font-size: 30px; background-color: green'>Foobar</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test2</td>
  </tr>

</table>






In Firefox, the height even seems to be 21.2px which is even more confusing.

